# fallback cache manifest does'nt work

Tags: html, caching, manifest, offline, fallback

I can't find another issue like mine so here it is:

I've got this cache manifest file :

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE: 
./index.html
./offlinetest.js
./offline.html
./cache.manifest
./cache.manifest.php
./online.html

# Hash: 800d285afdd44dae60eb95bf479a94bf

NETWORK:
./index.html
./online.html

FALLBACK:
./index.html ./offline.html
./online.html ./offline.html
```

When I turn off the wifi switch and if I try to reach online.html this file is served and not `offline.html`! Why? I'm using chrome.

Another Issue is with Firefox, when I try this I had :  `0 items in offline cache`

Can someone explain me that, I haven't see any issue like this everywhere I searched

Comment: You can check what files are being CACHED by the browser. Just change the hash. When that is done you should load the new site in Chrome and watch what files are cached in the console.

Comment: The hash is automatically generated with md5_file() php function, so if files change, hash change.
It is not the problem, the problem is why I never reach offline.html when I go offline.

Comment: According to the specs your server should also send expires headers with dates in the future for the files to be cached, if I understood that part correctly, have you configured that in your webserver?

Comment: Yes I've configured something in apache2.conf but not for text.html type:

ExpiresActive on

ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType text/js A2592000

Comment: try adding for `text/html` and `application/xhtml+xml` as well

Comment: Added this and restarted apache but no change

Answer (score 2):

You have `./online.html` under the `CACHE:` section. Remove it and your web app should retrieve the offline.html. The reason you are getting the online.html when disconnected is because you are caching it.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this myself, solution:

1. you have to clear your cache first
2. reload your page
3. reload again (sound stupid, i know), then the new version off the file will be used, and
   cached again off course.

then keep this syntax:

```
FALLBACK:
//static.html will be served if main.py is inaccessible
/main.py /static.html
//offline.jpg will be served in place of all images in images/large/
images/large/ images/offline.jpg
// offline.html will be served in place of all other .html files
*.html /offline.html
```

some more info that could help you:

FALLBACK:
An optional section specifying fallback pages if a resource is inaccessible. The first URI is the resource, the second is the fallback. **Both URIs must be relative and from the same origin as the manifest file.** Wildcards may be used.